# How to sort based on multiple fields with Go olivere/elastic

Tags: sorting, go, elasticsearch

I've been trying for days to know how to sort based on multiple fields with Go [`olivere/elastic`](https://github.com/olivere/elastic). I'm trying to translate this into Go

```
{
    "sort" : [
        "name",
        { "age" : "desc" },
    ],
}
```

I've tried to use the `NewFieldSort()` and give some `SortBy()` in the Search Service. It works fine with one `SortBy()` but won't work with two `SortBy()`. It returns `Error 400 (Bad Request): all shards failed [type=search_phase_execution_exception]`

Here's my code

```
    sortQuery1 := elastic.NewFieldSort("name")
    sortQuery2 := elastic.NewFieldSort("age").Desc()

    searchService := esclient.Search().
        Index("students").
        SortBy(sortQuery1).
        SortBy(sortQuery2)

    searchResult, err := searchService.Do(ctx)
```

Do you guys have any suggestions on what to try? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`SortBy`](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#SearchService.SortBy) function you're using in your example is variadic, as you can see from the signature: `SortBy(sorter ...Sorter) *SearchService`.

So you only need to call it once with both your filter conditions:

```
    sortQuery1 := elastic.NewFieldSort("name")
    sortQuery2 := elastic.NewFieldSort("age").Desc()

    searchService := client.Search().
        Index("students").
        SortBy(sortQuery1, sortQuery2)
```

Once this request body is marshalled to JSON, it will look like the following:

```
{
    "sort": [
        { "name": { "order": "asc" } },
        { "age": { "order": "desc" } }
    ]
}
```