# sorting elastic response based on multiple fields using olivere/elastic

Tags: sorting, go, elasticsearch

I want to Field sort based on multiple fields. I have a slice of `elastic.FieldSort` (say, sorter) and I want to do something like:

```
searchSource := elastic.NewSearchSource()
// searchSource.SortBy(sorter...)   // Unpacking of slice isn't working
```

I know that this `SortBy` accepts single elements as:

```
searchSource.SortBy(sorter[0], sorter[1], sorter[2])
```

but the issue is that I have a slice of dynamic size. Please help me how this can be implemented, or is there any better to do this?

Comment: in terms of the syntax, there is no reason the unpack should not work. https://play.golang.org/p/134i_Q0WrtP

Comment: are you sure the sorter slice you have is of the right type?

Comment: This is how I am building the slice:

`var sorter []elastic.FieldSort`

`sorter = append(sorter, *elastic.NewFieldSort(transformedField).Order(true)`

Comment: is this working? sorter is an array of elastic.FieldSort but NewFiledSort returns a *FieldSort it should not work

Comment: I guess I am able to build the slice by adding `*` before it, I also checked it by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The slice unpack would work if the type is right.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func print(data ...string) {
    fmt.Println(data)
}

func main() {
    d := []string{"hello", "world", "now"}
    print(d...)
}
```

For this specific example how if for any reason the unpack is not working still, there is a work around to this.

Since the SortBy function just appends to the underlying sorters slice https://github.com/olivere/elastic/blob/v7.0.22/search_source.go#L160

```
func (s *SearchSource) SortBy(sorter ...Sorter) *SearchSource {
    s.sorters = append(s.sorters, sorter...)
    return s
}
```

You can do

```
for _, sorter := range sorters {
    searchSource.SortBy(sorter)
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this, but it's throwing following error saying `elastic: Error 400 (Bad Request): all shards failed [type=search_phase_execution_exception]`

I found the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070742/how-to-sort-based-on-multiple-fields-with-go-olivere-elastic). 

Answer says that `searchSource.SortBy` can be called only once and that's why I was passing the slice to call this function one time only.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. There were two problems with my code.

First, I needed to initialize the slice (sorter) as type Sorter:

```
var sorter []elastic.Sorter
```

Second issue was on Elastic side. I needed to pass suffix `keyword` with keyword type fields like,

```
var fieldName string = field.FieldName
if field.Keyword {
    fieldName = field.FieldName + ".keyword"
}
```

And then use this `fieldName` to create `NewFieldSort`. This is why I was getting elastic error 404.

```
sorter = append(sorter, elastic.NewFieldSort(fieldName).Order(true)
```

Rest of the code was same, I was passing the sorter slice to the `sortBy` method:

```
searchSource.SortBy(sorter...)
```